# Can I dry out root rot in plants that survive on little water?

Tags: rot, lavender

I have a lavender plant that shows the typical signs of root rot. It is a small plant and I don't have the resources right now to re-pot it. I read that root rot is most commonly caused by funghi and I am wondering whether I can save my plant by not watering it for a long amount of time.

Do you know whether it is possible that the fungus dies before the plant does? If so, how long should I not water it?

Comment: If the plant is already stressed, my bet is on the fungus. New soil would be best, but barring that, do you have any anti-fungal substances around? Tinactin, nizoral, lotrimin, roach powder, etc...

Comment: Would caffeine do? I have none of those.

Comment: It's not something i've heard of using before.